# Need to make a loop out of my hard-code

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, loops, maze

I'm writing a maze algorithm code and I have hard coded a part of it for now, but I need to change this into a loop for scalability. Can someone please help me how to turn this into a loop?

```
movement(x_3_vector.at(1),y_3_vector.at(1),x_4_vector.at(1),y_4_vector.at(1),"3");
movement(x_3_vector.at(2),y_3_vector.at(2),x_4_vector.at(2),y_4_vector.at(2),"3");
movement(x_3_vector.at(3),y_3_vector.at(3),x_4_vector.at(3),y_4_vector.at(3),"3");


 movement(x_3_vector.at(4),y_3_vector.at(4),x_4_vector.at(4),y_4_vector.at(4),"4");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(5),y_3_vector.at(5),x_4_vector.at(5),y_4_vector.at(5),"4");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(6),y_3_vector.at(6),x_4_vector.at(6),y_4_vector.at(6),"4");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(7),y_3_vector.at(7),x_4_vector.at(7),y_4_vector.at(7),"4");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(8),y_3_vector.at(8),x_4_vector.at(8),y_4_vector.at(8),"4");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(9),y_3_vector.at(9),x_4_vector.at(9),y_4_vector.at(9),"4");


 movement(x_3_vector.at(10),y_3_vector.at(10),x_4_vector.at(10),y_4_vector.at(10),"5");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(11),y_3_vector.at(11),x_4_vector.at(11),y_4_vector.at(11),"5");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(12),y_3_vector.at(12),x_4_vector.at(12),y_4_vector.at(12),"5");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(13),y_3_vector.at(13),x_4_vector.at(13),y_4_vector.at(13),"5");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(14),y_3_vector.at(14),x_4_vector.at(14),y_4_vector.at(14),"5");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(15),y_3_vector.at(15),x_4_vector.at(15),y_4_vector.at(15),"5");

 movement(x_3_vector.at(16),y_3_vector.at(16),x_4_vector.at(16),y_4_vector.at(16),"6");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(17),y_3_vector.at(17),x_4_vector.at(17),y_4_vector.at(17),"6");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(18),y_3_vector.at(18),x_4_vector.at(18),y_4_vector.at(18),"6");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(19),y_3_vector.at(19),x_4_vector.at(19),y_4_vector.at(19),"6");
 movement(x_3_vector.at(20),y_3_vector.at(20),x_4_vector.at(20),y_4_vector.at(20),"6");
```

The problem is that I need to call the "movement" function depending on how many cells in my maze I occupy, so sometimes I need to call the movement function 3 times with the string "3" and sometimes I need to call it 6 times with the string "4"...and so on...

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know how many times call it?

Comment: What do mean by "I need to call this function...sometimes...3 times...sometimes 6...sometimes 5"?  What function?  `movement`?  Or a new function that replaces your hard-coded values and itself calls `movement`?  Also, what do those indices mean?  Are they always increasing?  What is that string value at the end doing?  Anything significant to your question?  You should probably edit your question for clarity, because as posed it is unclear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I just modified the question so maybe it's more understandable.

Comment: @ShahinB: still unclear how `"3"` may be computed. Does it depend of index ? of `x_3_vector` content ?

Comment: the strings just go up after the required number of the "movement" function are called....so for instance I need to call movement with string "4" six times and then I'm done with that so I move to the next string!

Answer (score 1):

Your current code with a loop:

```
const char* s[20] = {
    "3", "3", "3",
    "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4",
    "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5",
    "6", "6", "6", "6", "6"
    };
for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
    movement(x_3_vector.at(1 + i),
             y_3_vector.at(1 + i),
             x_4_vector.at(1 + i),
             y_4_vector.at(1 + i),
             s[i]);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve it because sometimes I need to call the movement function 3 times with the string "3" and sometimes I need to call it 6 times with the string "4"...and so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
     movement(x_3_vector.at(i),y_3_vector.at(i),x_4_vector.at(i),y_4_vector.at(i), getParam(i));
}

// TODO: improve this function in order to reflect what the string value must be at any time
string getParam(int index) {
    // TODO: make sure it's between 1-20 or whatever your constraints are
    if (index >= 16) return "6";
    else if (index >= 10) return "5";
    else if (index >= 4) return "4";
    else return "3";
}
```